# Windows 10 apply visible columns to all folders

Tags: windows-10, default-settings

Is there any way to apply visible column settings on entire OS?

For example, I added URL column for this sub folder, but this does not apply for all folders.

[image: url column]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you are viewing the folder whose settings you want to copy to everywhere. On the View tab of the ribbon, click Options to produce the Folder Options tab. On the View tab of that dialog, click the *Apply to Folders* button and confirm your decision.

[image: folder options]

Once that's done, the Details view as well as the columns you've selected will apply to all folders of the same type.

The "type" of a folder is governed by the "Optimize this folder for" setting on the Customize tab of the folder's properties. If you perform the above process from a folder optimized for documents, the settings won't apply to folders for general items. You might have to do the column setup and copy for each folder type. If you don't want to alter all folders of a given type, you can just change a folder's type and it will receive that type's view settings.

[image: folder properties]

Comment: It's incredible that it took me this long to finally find mention of what "this type" means. This whole folder view "types" thing could have been done WAY better. It would have been awesome to have proper templates rather than this limited system with the interface split across two mostly unrelated dialogues and not explained in any useful way. It's no wonder lots of people hate Windows (I myself not among them).